# Div uma em cima da outra

Tags: css

Tenho uma sequencia de DIVs sendo geradas por um script.
Gostaria que elas ficassem uma em baixo da outra e quando atingisse a altura máxima da div pai, elas entrariam do lado .
Atualmente colocando-as para flutuar à esquerda ficam assim:

[ 0 ] [ 1 ]
[ 2 ] [ 3 ]
[ 4 ] [ 5 ]
[ 6 ] [ 7 ]

Mas gostaria que elas ficassem assim:

[ 0 ] [ 4 ]
[ 1 ] [ 5 ]
[ 2 ] [ 6 ]
[ 3 ] [ 7 ]

Código até o momento:

```
<style>
     #pai{
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
     }

     .filhos{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
     }
</style>

<div id="pai">     
     <? for($x=0;$x<24;$x++){ ?>
          <div class="filhos"><?=$x?></div>
     <? } ?> 
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgveahjp/

Comment: Complemente com o código que você já tem.

Comment: Editado com o código !

Comment: Usando a propriedade flex-box do css3 consegui fazer oque você precisa, porem o width da div pai não acompanha os filhos, é fixo, talvez de para arrumar isto.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/zgveahjp/2/

Referência: http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox/

Can i use?: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVIDO !
De acordo com o comentário do devgaspa.
Achei mais simples e como resolveu, nem testei outros métodos.
OBRIGADO

> Usando a propriedade flex-box do css3 consegui fazer oque você
>   precisa, porem o width da div pai não acompanha os filhos, é fixo,
>   talvez de para arrumar isto. JSFiddle:
>   jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/zgveahjp/2 Referência:
>   desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox Can i use?:
>   caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox – devgaspa

```css
.pai {
    background: orange;
    
    display: flex;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    height: 500px;
    width: 0px;
}

.filhos {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">     
    <div class="filhos">0</div>
    <div class="filhos">1</div>
    <div class="filhos">2</div>
    <div class="filhos">3</div>
    <div class="filhos">4</div>
    <div class="filhos">5</div>
    <div class="filhos">6</div>
    <div class="filhos">7</div>
    <div class="filhos">8</div>
    <div class="filhos">9</div>
    <div class="filhos">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte maneira com jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divPai = $("#idPai");

    if (divPai.height() <= 200) {
        divPai.addClass("umaColuna").removeClass("duasColunas");
    } else {
        divPai.addClass("duasColunas").removeClass("umaColuna");
    }
});
```

### Basicamente o que isto vai fazer é:

Se a `div id="divPai"` for menor ou igual a `400px` de altura (ou seja lá qual for o valor que queiras que seja o valor máximo definido para a altura da div pai), vai adicionar uma classe chamada `umaColuna` ao `#divPai`:

```
<div id="divPai" class="umaColuna">
```

e se o valor for maior, adiciona uma classe `duasColunas`:

```
<div id="divPai" class="duasColunas">
```

Depois para fazermos a modificação e transação para dividirmos o conteúdo dentro do `#divPai` para que ele fique com **uma** ou **duas** colunas dependendo desta mudança de classes acima, basta criarmos o código CSS referente para as classes da seguinte forma:

```
/* Personaliza o espaçamento entre as colunas */
#idPai {
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 15px;
}

/* Divide o conteúdo dentro da #divPai em uma coluna */
.umaColuna {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
}

/* Divide o conteúdo dentro da #divPai em duas colunas */
.duasColunas {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}

.classFilho {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    margin: 0 2px 15px 2px;
/* O código abaixo evita problemas de posicionamento das divs filhos */
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

E o código HTML será algo como:

```
<div id="idPai">
    <div class="classFilho">0</div>
    <div class="classFilho">1</div>
    <div class="classFilho">2</div>
    <div class="classFilho">3</div>
</div>
```

Aqui tens um exemplo online no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6sqmsLvv/
Clica no botão <kbd>Adicionar nova div Filho</kbd> no link do exemplo, para adicionar novas `divs` filho.

Answer (score -1):

pra ele não passar de 300px coloque a tag

```
 max-height: 300px;
```

Comment: Realmente. Mas isso não soluciona o problema que estou enfrentando.